# Rhetorica ad Herennium - English translation

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

What is the definition of the word 'Herennium'?
I can find no explanation online other than what the book is generally about.

Answer (score 8):

It's just a name: "Herennius". The book was dedicated to someone named Gaius Herennius, who's unknown except for that dedication. But other authors mention people named Marcus Herennius, Herennius Gallus, Herennius Senecio, etc in various contexts, so it's decently attested as a gens.

Answer (score 7):

Herennius is a name, and the text is dedicated to him. He is otherwise unknown to history, however.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herennia_gens#Members